# Why does print() isn't affected by operator precedence?

Tags: perl, parsing, operators, side-effects

I was making an operator precendence and associativity table for C when I obtained a weird result in my tests, for which Perl as the same weird behvior a priori.

The `**` power operator is **right associative**, which means that expressions are evaluated right to left.

It obviously work with arithmetic exprssions correctly, but weirdly, it doesn't produce the expected result with the print function call.

I expected this to output `321`

```
$ perl -E 'print("1") ** print("2") ** print("3"); say ""'
123
```

but it produce `123`

This also happens with user-defined function:

```
$ perl -E 'sub my_print { print $_[0] } my_print(1) ** my_print(2) ** my_print(3); say ""'
123
```

Even more weird,

```
$ perl -E 'sub my_print { say $_[0]; $_[0] } say my_print(2) ** my_print(2) ** my_print(4);'
2
2
4
65536
```

when we defined a function with a `print` side effect which alos return a value. The result of the arithmetic expression has the correct expected value, with the evaluation in the order defined by the operator associativity, but the `print` still defies operator associativity.

It's as if there were 2 order of evaluations.

- The normal order of evaluation, which is defined by the AST and the algorithm wakling over it to evaluate it (or more likely during the "evaluation-order pass" explained in `man perlguts` and `op.c`).
- A second evaluation order for the side-effets or I/O where it seems that function calls of builtin that have a side effects are put in a queue, which brings the question: In which order are they placed

I am going to assume that it is not a bug, but a feature. If it were a bug it would have been discovered long time ago.

So this bring my actual question :
**What is the rational for this behavior ?**
and
**How is it implemented ?**. (meaning which data structures are used and during which compile time phase does this happens).

If I'm right thinking that there are an AST level queue somewhere, in **which order are the `print` calls enqueued ?**

**EDIT1:**
As an additional precision, I know that queues are involved during I/O, but it doesn't change the fact that I/O operations are normally enqueued in the evaluation order of the program, not in an arbitrary left-to-right order of the program text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing operand evaluation order and operator precedence/associativity.

---

Operator associativity dictates if

```c
X ** Y ** Z          // 2 ** 2 ** 3, for example
```

means

```c
( X ** Y ) ** Z      // ( 2 ** 2 ) ** 3 = 64
```

or

```c
X ** ( Y ** Z )      // 2 ** ( 2 ** 3 ) = 256
```

As you mentioned, `**` is right-associative, so it means the latter.

It has nothing do with the order in which `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `Y ** Z` are evaluated relative to each other. As long as `Y` and `Z` are evaluated before `Y ** Z`, the above produces the same result no matter the order in which those four expressions are calculated.

Some conclusions can be drawn. As mentioned, `Y` and `Z` obviously need be evaluated before `Y ** Z`. But absent such requirements<sup>[1]</sup>, and absent explicit statements to the contrary in the documentation<sup>[2]</sup>, the operators can be evaluated in an order of the compiler's choosing.

---

1. Another example is that short-circuiting operators necessarily need to evaluate their left-hand side operand before their right-hand side operand.
2. The comma operator is guaranteed to evaluate each operand in order.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification. IMHO it should be specified that evaluation order should coincide with operator precedence and associativity. Just for the sake of side-effects. But maybe there is another aspect that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Bearing in mind what you said about the distinction between evaluation order and operator precedence, I think it is weird that there are special cases for some of the operators. It seems a little arbitrary, even if it make sense (for the comma operator). Even more so for the short-circuit, if we think about it as a conditional.

Comment: I mean it should be in the spec just when side-effects are involved.

Comment: @WhiteMist [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) has a paragraph about this (by "this" I mean, about "associativity != evaluation order"). It mentions "In fact Perl has a general rule that the operands of an operator are evaluated in left-to-right order". So, it's actually specified that evaluation order does not coincide with operator precedence.

Comment: @Dada Thanks for the tip, I missed this. I think it might explain the behavior of my examples, I'm not exactly sure. It's unambiguous, but it only talk about the evluation order of operadns of one operator, not what appens in an expression with more than 1 operators, but I get the point.

Comment: I had to make minor wording changes cause I thought this was a [tag:c] question when I wrote it. The behaviour is hardly unique to Perl. That said, Perl's evaluation order is extremely predictable/stable.